# Two rules in one .htaccess file not working

Tags: .htaccess

Below is my code for .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /products/product-full-view.php?src=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /products/product-full-view.php?src=$1&id=$2

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /buy/buy-full-view.php?src=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /buy/buy-full-view.php?src=$1&id=$2
```

First rule is working fine but its not taking the second rule...Unable to understand what is happening here...

Original URL's are like this 
www.example.com/products/product-full-view.php?src=somevalue&id=somevalue

and for second one 
www.example.com/buy/buy-full-view.php?src=somevalue&id=somevalue

Please help me to run second rule also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your second set of rules is identical to the first set of rules. If the first set of rules matches, the second set of rules will never match. Give the first set of rules and the second set of rules a common prefix (e.g. `/products/airplanes/235` and `/buy/airplanes/235`). If you can't do that, you'll have to use a router page that intelligently guesses what page it should show. This is less than ideal though.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match the same pattern, give or take an optional trailing slash, four times. By the time you reach the last two rules, your URL is already rewritten to something else.

You probably want something that looks more like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ /products/product-full-view.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^buy/([0-9]+)/?$      /buy/buy-full-view.php?id=$1          [L]
```

Or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /products/product-full-view.php?src=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^buy/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$      /buy/buy-full-view.php?src=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Or something to that order anyway.

Note the stub and the `[L]` each time: the `products/` and `buy/` avoid that the same URL refers to two different locations, and the `[L]` (for "Last") tells the rewrite engine to stop processing rules when it gets matched.

Answer (score 0):

If a URL matches the second rule, it also matches the first rule. After applying the first rule, the resulting URL no longer matches the second rule. That's why the second rule is never applied.